# Understanding L-infinity norm which is used in TFDV

Tags: tensorflow, threshold, skew, drift, tensorflow-data-validation

I was trying to implement TensorFlow Data Validation to check drift/skew in a dataset. They are using the L-infinity norm as a metric. I didn't understand the concept. **Can anyone explain how it is calculated and why they used threshold as a 0.01 here ?**

```
 train_day1_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(data_location=train_day1_data_path)
# Add a drift comparator to schema for 'payment_type' and set the threshold of L-infinity norm for triggering drift anomaly to be 0.01.
**tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'payment_type').drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold = 0.01**
drift_anomalies = tfdv.validate_statistics(
    statistics=train_day2_stats, schema=schema, previous_statistics=train_day1_stats)
```

[Tensorflow Website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n08n.png)

Answer (score 1):

The COMPARATOR_L_INFTY_HIGH is triggered as follows:

- Used Schema Fields:
      * feature.skew_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold.
      * feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold
- Statistics Fields:
      * feature.string_stats.rank_histogram
- Detection Condition: L-infinity
  norm of the vector that represents the difference between the
  normalized counts from the feature.string_stats.rank_histogram in the
  control statistics (i.e., serving statistics for skew or previous
  statistics for drift) and the treatment statistics (i.e., training
  statistics for skew or current statistics for drift) >
  feature.skew_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold or
  feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold

The L-infinity form is basically abs(max([x1,....,xn])
In this case x1 = count(values bucket1)/total values in control set - count(values bucket1)/total values in treatment set.
Once we have the L-inf we check > (feature.skew_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold or feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold)
And if so, COMPARATOR_L_INFTY_HIGH is triggered.
The actual value(0.01) needs to be fine-tuned based on your particular case and data stats.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed detection conditions are explained in tensor flow documentation (link below),

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/anomalies

for your case it mentions,

`COMPARATOR_L_INFTY_HIGH`

**Schema Fields:**

`feature.skew_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold`

**Statistics Fields:**

`feature.string_stats.rank_histogram*`

**Detection Condition:**
L-infinity norm of the vector that represents the difference between the normalized counts from the `feature.string_stats.rank_histogram` in the control statistics (i.e., serving statistics for skew or previous statistics for drift) and the treatment statistics (i.e., training statistics for skew or current statistics for drift) `> feature.skew_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold` or `feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold`